# how the subString() function of string class works

Tags: java, string

please see the following code.

```
String s = "Monday";
if(s.subString(0,3).equals("Mon"){}

String s2 = new String(s.subString(0,3));
String s3 = s.subString(0,3);
```

I know that line 2 will still point to "Monday" and have a new String object with the offset and count set to 0,3.

The line 4 will create a new String "Mon" in string pool and point to it.

But not sure what about line 5 whether it will behave like line 2 or line 4.

If i am wrong for line 2 or 4 also please correct..

Comment: I was wondering, where my answer got lost. Then I realized I answered at Ranch. :)

Comment: That method of String is spelled all lowercase: substring()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that line 2 will still point to "Monday" and have a new String object with the offset and count set to 0,3.

That is currently true of the Sun JRE implementation. I seem to recall that was not true of the Sun implementation in the past, and is not true of other implementations of the JVM. Do not rely on behaviour which is not specified. GNU classpath might copy the array (I can't remember off hand what ratio is uses to decide when to copy, but it does copy if the copy is a small enough fraction of the original, which turned one nice O(N) algorithm to O(N^2)).

> The line 4 will create a new String "Mon" in string pool and point to it.

No, it creates a new string object in the heap, subject to the same garbage collection rules as any other object. Whether or not it shares the same underlying character array is implementation dependant. Do not rely on behaviour which is not specified.

The [`String(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)) constructor says:

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it **represents the same sequence of characters** as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string.

The [`String(char[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) constructor says:

> Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument. The **contents of the character array** are copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the newly created string.

Following good OO principles, no method of `String` actually requires that it is implemented using a character array, so no part of the specification of `String` requires operations on an character array. Those operations which take an array as input specify that the **contents** of the array are copied to whatever internal storage is used in the String.  A string could use UTF-8 or LZ compression internally and conform to the API.

However, if your JVM doesn't make the small-ratio sub-string optimisation, then there's a chance that it does copy only the relevant portion when you use `new String(String)`, so it's a case of trying it a seeing if it improves the memory use. Not everything which effects Java runtimes is defined by Java.

To obtain a string in the string pool which is `equal` to a string, use the [`intern()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) method. This will either retrieve a string from the pool if one with the value already has been interned, or create a new string and put it in the pool. Note that pooled strings have different (again implementation dependent) garbage collection behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Pete for nice explanation. "the newly created string is a copy of the argument string." So where is the argument string stored.

Comment: Like any object in Java, it's stored in the heap until it's no longer referenced, and is then garbage collected sometime. All implementations I've seen use a char array to store the characters in the string, and some have different rules for sharing this array between Strings...

Comment: ... but I can't recall one where String(String) doesn't end up with the array being the same length as the new String. So the array used internally by the argument may be copied or may be referenced, but that's up to the implementation.

Answer (score 9):

**As pointed out by Pete Kirkham, this is implementation specific. My answer is only correct for the Sun JRE, and only prior to Java 7 update 6.**

You're right about a normal `substring` call just creating a new string referring to the same character array as the original string. That's what happens on line 5 too. The fact that the new string object reference happens to be assigned to a variable doesn't change the behaviour of the method.

Just to be clear, you say that in line 2 the new string will still point to "Monday" - the char array reference inside the string will be to the same char array as one used for "Monday". But "Monday" is a string in itself, not a char array. In other words, by the time line 2 has finished (and ignoring GC) there are two string objects, both referring to the same char array. One has a count of 6 and the other has a count of 3; both have an offset of 0.

You're wrong about line 4 using a "string pool" though - there's no pooling going on there. However, it is different to the other lines. When you call the `String(String)` constructor, the new string takes a *copy* of the character data of the original, so it's completely separate. This can be very useful if you only need a string which contains a small part of a very large original string; it allows the original large char array to be garbage collected (assuming nothing else needs it) while you hold onto the copy of the small portion. A good example of this in my own experience is reading lines from a line. By default, `BufferedLineReader` will read lines using an 80-character buffer, so every string returned will use a char array of at least 80 characters. If you're reading lots of very short lines (single words) the difference in terms of memory consumption just through the use of the odd-looking

```
line = new String(line);
```

can be very significant.

Does that help?

Comment: See my post. This is implementation defined and varies.

Comment: As of Java 7 update 6, the Sun JRE has [scrapped the array sharing behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704319/how-the-substring-function-of-string-class-works/13386284#13386284).

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: As of Java 7 update 6 in Sun/Oracle's Java, it is no longer true that a String created by String.substring shares the parent's char array. It was decided that this optimization was rarely beneficial, and did not justify the cost and complexity of the `offset` and `count` fields.

Some links:

- Rationale: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html
- Formal bug report: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6924259
- String.java diff: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/diff/e1c679a00712/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Answer (score 1):

At line 5---->s3=Mon .

Answer (score 0):

In Sun's implementation String objects have a `private final char value[]` field. When you create a new String by calling substring(), no new char array is created, the new instance uses the `value` of the original object. This is the case in line 2 and 5, the new String objects will use the char array of s.

The constructor String(String) creates a new char array in case of the string length being  less than the total length of the char array `value`. So the String created in line 4 will use a new char array.

You should have a look at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#151) of the constructor public String(String original), it's really simple.

Answer (score 0):

**“Substring creates a new object out of source string by taking a portion of original string”.**

Until Java 1.7, substring holds the reference of the original character array, which means even a sub-string of 5 characters long, can prevent 1GB character array from garbage collection, by holding a strong reference.

This issue is fixed in Java 1.7, where original character array is not referenced anymore, but that change also made the creation of substring bit costly in terms of time. Earlier it was in the range of O(1), which could be O(n) in worst case on Java 7.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

> "Returns a new string..."

Comment: I believe the question is really about when strings share an underlying char array and when they don't.