# Is this creating 12 string objects?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand if this code below creates 12 objects for a string like "stephan"

```
public String reverse(String str) {
            if ((null == str) || (str.length()  <= 1)) {
                return str;
            }
            return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
        }
```

This recursively reverses a string. I understand how it works. But I was thinking if there is a relationship in this case between the length of the strings and number of string objects created through concatenation?

Comment: substring() will create a String object.  The + will create another one.  I don't know what you mean by a relationship to the length of the string, though.

Comment: Let's just say "on the order of the number of letters".

Comment: @Marvo - his function is recursive. So that count will happen once per character on each recursive call

Comment: substring does not create a string, it returns a view to the original string - the + however does.

Comment: I realize it's recursive.  I was pointing out where in the code Strings are created.  The input would determine the final count.

Comment: @Amir Afghani: JDK 1.6 source code claims to return a `new String` (see below).

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704319/how-the-substring-function-of-string-class-works indicates that while some implementations may re-use the backing character buffer when performing substring, a new String object is created in the heap.

Comment: From String.substring: `return new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);`. So, yes the char-array (value) is re-used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will create tons of string objects.

Every recursive call to "reverse()" will create 2:

1. `str.substring(1)` will create a new String object
2. `reverse()` call will create a new string for its return value, but we will NOT count that since that's counted when analyzing that recursive call (e.g. it will be the string from bullet point #3 from the next `reverse()` call).
3. And since Java Strings [are immutable](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html), adding a char via "`+`" will create a **second** String object.

Therefore, for a string of length N, it will create (N-1)*2 objects (since a reverse of 1-char string does NOT create new strings); **so for "stephan"'s 7 characters, it will create 6*2=12 string objects.**

Comment: So will charAt(0) which returns a char also be converted to a string before concatenation ?

Comment: Don't forget the StringBuilders created to actually concatenate each intermediate result and the next char.

Comment: @Phoenix: No, characters aren't converted to strings, the byte-code will look something like `new StringBuilder().append(string).append(char).toString();`

Comment: @EthanB - StringBuilder doesn't count as a String object, no? Mind you, as far as resource allocation it's still an object; but the OP explicitly asked about strings

Comment: @DVK Nope. It's used for the concatenation. (OP probably doesn't know about the byte-code.)

Comment: So the first call is (tephan) + s .. FOr this one alone will it be counted as 2 OR 3 objects ? 1 for whatever is the return value from (tephan) and one for "s" and one for the concatenation result ? What I am reading from the previous comments is the char will not be converted to "s" so this means only 2 will be created

Comment: @Phoenix: "tephan" (1) and the string-builder to append the "s" (2), and the reversed result (3). Individual chars don't count.

Comment: @EthanB how is it 12 then ? if for every call 3 are being created except the last one ?

Comment: @Phoenix - because StringBuilder is not a String. it's 12 Strings and 18 objects

Comment: @DVK - but they're all `CharSequence`s! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Theorem:

- When a string is `N` characters long, @Phoenix's `reverse` implementation will create `(N-1)*3` new objects.

Proof (by induction):

- When str is 1 character long, it is returned directly. `(1*1)*3 = 0`.
- When str is N characters long:

  - a new `String` will be created by `.substring(1)`.
  - by the induction hypothesis, the call to `reverse(...)` will be returned after `(N-2)*3` objects have been created.
  - a new `StringBuilder` will be created to append the string and first `char` (you can see this by de-compiling your byte-code).
  - a new `String` will be created by `StringBuilder.toString()`--this is the return value.
  - Altogether, there were `3 + (N-2)*3 = (N-2 + 1)*3 = (N-1)*3` objects created.
- QED.

---

[Edit] StringBuilders:

- StringBuilder (extending AbstractStringBuilder) does its own fancy footwork:

  - When an `StringBuilder` is constructed, it is initialized with a `char[]` of size 16.
  - When you append something more than it's present size, it throws that away and creates a new `char[]` of size `(<old size> + <size of new data> + 1) * 2`.
- So, as soon as your input string is > 16 characters, you have essentially 2x as much StringBuilder capacity as you need. (When the input string size is less, you've got more `char[]` than you need.)
- Considering `String`s are essentially `char[]`s (with a few `int`s for good measure), you're effectively using 4 times the length of the substring in `char[]`s -- at each step. :(