# string object creation and its constructor

Tags: java

There are two ways to create String object.

```
String str = new String("Java");
String str2 = "Java";
```

I know in first case constructor will definitely be invoked. But not aware about second one.
Will constructor be invoked?

```
String substr = new String(str.substring(2,str.length));  // str is new object
String substr2 = new String(str2.substring(2,str2.length)); //str2 is not with new keyword
```

want to make sure `substr` and `substr2` are same kind of operation and same behaviour in the heap memory.

I know one thing that `String.substring()` doesn't create new object at all but uses previous char[] object with different offset.

so what happen with `substr` and `substr2`? Can we relate these things with constructor as offset is generated inside constructor.

Comment: @NPE I'd ask such question only to understand the language well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JLS [§3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class `String` (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Thus, `"Java"` refers to a `String` object. Furthermore, any string literal consisting of the same charactes would refer to the same `String` object. However, how and when this object is constructed is unspecified.

> want to make sure `substr` and `substr2` are same kind of operation and same behaviour in the heap memory.

Yes, they are exactly the same kind of operation.

> I know one thing that `String.substring()` doesn't create new object at all but uses previous char[] object with different offset.

This is unspecified. What you describe is how older versions of Oracle's JDK worked. Current versions [don't do that anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193606/367273): `substring()` now copies the characters. This change was made in Java 7u6.

Comment: @AmitG: I think the current answer addresses every point of your question.

Comment: Can you please refer a link for "The current versions don't do that anymore". Anyways I am googling it now...

Answer (score 2):

constructor is invoked when any object is created.

In case of `String str2 = "World";`, jvm will first search for the string `"world"` in the string pool. the constructor will be called only if this literal doesn't exist in pool, otherwise it will return the existing object.

Comment: be it any possible literal, the logic will be same.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor should always be invoked.
To find out for yourself debug this application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = new String("Java"); // <-- breakpoint here
  String str2 = "World";
  String str3 = "Java"; // (1)
  String str4 = new String("Java"); // (2)

  System.out.println(str + " " + str2 + " " + str3 + " " + str4);
}
```

Set the breakpoint on the first line (`String str = new...`) and "Step into" to go into the `String()` constructor. Then "Step out" of the constructor, "Step over" to the next line and "Step into" again. You should be in the `String()` constructor again.

1: As for `str3` it should come from the pool, i.e. `if (str3 == str)` will be `true`.

2: But `str4` will be a new instance, i.e. `if (str4 == str || str4 == str3)` will be `false`. See the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29).

Let us know what you found :-)

Comment: it is not a generalized answer, try adding String str3 = "World";

Comment: please see my updated question. I have change "World" to "Java" again.

Comment: Check the updated example, specifically str4 and the String API.