# Extracting the initial characters from a string in one go

Tags: java, string

please advise below is the code to extract the first 4 characters from the string as shown below..

```
String external = ak.getReference();    
String s= external.substring(0,4);
```

Can I wrap this into one so that no extra String s need to be created and finally string external will have four initial characters in one go

Comment: `String external = ak.getReference().substring(0,4);`?

Comment: By extra String, do you mean extra String reference, or String object? Later is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always chain the method calls...

```
String s = ak.getReference().substring(0,4);
```

... But that doesn't mean that an extra string won't be created, starting with Java 7u6 the `substring()` method will return a new `String` object with a freshly allocated `char[]` (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193606/201359)). You're just eliminating an intermediate local variable, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Same strings are going to be created no matter what. Compiler will optimize that anyways. Otherwise the comment of @ZouZou is correct.

```
String external = ak.getReference().substring(0,4);
```