# Memory allocation for matcher.group()

Tags: java, android, regex, memory-management, substring

I want to use regex to parse a huge `String largeString`.

I am using `matcher.group()` to obtain substrings of `largeString`. My question is:

Do matcher.group() returns a new `String` object, or it only returns a substring reference to `largeString` ?

As far as I know defining substring only allocates memory for a pointer and 3 `int` instances. I want to keep `largeString` for other purposes, so I will prefer keeping substring instances instead of creating new `String`.

Comment: @fge: A question related to your `CharSequence` thing...I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered elsewhere, to some extent.

Since Java 7u6, all substrings are their own `String` object. So you would not just allocate memory for 16 more bytes, you would allocate memory for a whole `String` object.

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193606/1159805

edit: Here's a copy of the proposal explaining why the change was made: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at an old blog post :P
That means if I want to save memory, say, I instead store matcher.start() and end()? (just 2 `int`) and call substring method later on the fly?

Comment: @Ivan That's right, but remember that calling `substring` *will* create a whole new `String` object.

Comment: since the `substring` is on the fly, they are used temporarily and will be garbage collected.