# Memory issues with substring

Tags: java, string, substring

How does `substring` method work internally and how can it create memory issue ?

How can we solve it?

Comment: Because `substring` returns a new String and it's unclear what you're asking, please put more efforts when asking a question.

Comment: So, which kind of memory issue is reported?

Comment: Have a look here. http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/
In Java < 7 there might be situations where more memory is allocated then needed from a application logic point of view.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193571/how-does-java-store-strings-and-how-does-substring-work-internally?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Java 7 udate 6, `substring` used to return a *view* on the original string. So imagine you had a String of 1,000,000 characters and called `s.substring(0, 1)` because you are only interested in the first character, the original string would have stayed in memory.

Since Java 7u6 `substring` returns a new string which prevents that issue.

Comment: Of course, if you needed 300 views of 100,000 of that 1,000,000 characters, the new version might make you sad. Can't make everyone happy...

Comment: @assylias : that's exactly what i want to know . how did they solved the unnecessary memory allocation in next version

Comment: Interesting. I knew about the issue and knew I had to enclose the substring in a 'new String()', if I want to release the original string. I didn't know this behaviour was changed in Java 7. So, how can I avoid much memory usage, if I do much substrings on an original String now?

Comment: @DeenJohn They just create a new string instead of sharing the underlying `char[]`.

Comment: @assylias: thanks, that's helpful :)